# How to remove spacing after centering

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, vertical-spacing, center

**Question:** How do I remove the spacing after the centered text "FALSE:" below?  I'll need to do this for five centered spots in the document.

```
% BEGIN PREAMBLE

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{calc}
\fancyheadoffset[L,R]{45pt}
\nofiles
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{microtype}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1.25in}%-1.25
\addtolength{\textheight}{5in}%1.75in

% END PREAMBLE

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{NAME}}\\
\normalsize something 123456789
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\textbf{FALSE:}
\end{center}

This is some text.

This is some more text.

This is even more text for display.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `\centerline{\textbf{FALSE:}}` instead of using the environment `center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment which adds space after the environment.

```
% centerprob.tex  SE 645778

\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
% END PREAMBLE

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large{\textbf{NAME}}\\
\normalsize something 123456789
\end{center}

%\begin{center}
{\centering \textbf{FALSE:}\par}
%\end{center}

This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.

This is some more text.

This is even more text for display.

\end{document}
```

[image]